# SQL query for 3 sub queries with self join

Tags: sql, oracle

Please give some advise how to achieve the below required output.

```
Table1 data
-----------
request_id    record_type  invoice_number      merchant_info          transaction_info
----------    -----------  -----------------   ----------------    -----------------------
123             01              NULL                NULL                  Trans1
123             30              NULL                Merc1                  NULL
123             02              Invoice1            NULL                   NULL
123             01              NULL                NULL                   Trans2
123             30              NULL                Merc2                  NULL
123             02              Invoice2            NULL                   NULL
124             01              NULL                NULL                  Trans3
124             30              NULL                Merc3                 NULL
124             02              Invoice3            NULL                   NULL
124             01              NULL                NULL                   Trans4
124             30              NULL                Merc4                  NULL
124             02              Invoice4            NULL                   NULL
```

Required output

```
---------------
invoice_number      merchant_info          transaction_info
--------------     --------------           -----------------
Invoice1             Merc1                     Trans1
Invoice2             Merc2                     Trans2
Invoice3             Merc3                     Trans3
Invoice4             Merc4                     Trans4



SELECT xpt.transaction_info,XTG.merchant_info,x.invoice_number
FROM (select * from table1
WHERE record_type='01' )xpt,
 (SELECT *
 FROM table1
 WHERE record_type='30'
 ) XTG,
 (SELECT *
 FROM table1
 WHERE record_type='02'
 and invoice_number is not null
 ) X
 WHERE 1=1 
 and xtg.request_id=xpt.request_id
and x.request_id=xpt.request_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use aggregation:

```
select request_id, max(invoice_number) as invoice_number,
       max(merchant_info) as merchant_info,
       max(transaction_info) as transaction_info
from table1
group by request_id;
```

Comment: `select invoice_number ...` and `group by request_id`?

Comment: We don't need the data grouped. Also every record is returning null value for one or more than one fields. We have given sample data. according to which we required the same. Not the grouped data. Please advise

Comment: I see a table with 3 records, and an output with 1 row, containing data from each of the table records, that seems grouping. If not, can you give a clearer example ?

Comment: @jarlh . . . I'm embarrassed.  Cheers.

Comment: Still not that clear to me; `Invoice1` and `Invoice2` have the same `request_id` and `record_type`; so, how can I say that `Invoice1` matches `Merc1` and `Trans1` and not `Merc2` or `Trans2`. Is there any ordering in your data?

Answer (score 1):

Try some conditional aggregation:

```
select max (decode ( record_type, '01', transaction_info, null)) as transaction_info, 
       max (decode ( record_type, '30', merchant_info,    null)) as merchant_info,
       max (decode ( record_type, '02', invoice_number,   null)) as invoice_number
from table1
group by request_id
```